# How to split a string with more than one whitespaces as delimiters?

Tags: c#, string

I have strings where one whitespace must not be a delimiter. But when more than one whitespaces occur consecetively, it must act as delimiter. e.g.

```
"Line 1     Component Name             Revision        Quantity   Unit"
```

Here in this example I must have  5 different elements after split. How can I implement it with built-in split function in string. (please note that single occurence of whitespace do not act as delimiter)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks, this should work:  `s.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Is "whitespace" only "spaces" or does it cover other whitespace characters (newlines, tabs, etc.) as well? EDIT: And if so, are those also bound by the "more than one whitespace" rule? So a single tab or single newline should be ignored, but two tabs, or one space+one tab, or newline+space, or newline+tab, or two newlines would be valid to split?

Comment: there is not tabs inside. The data is imported from MFG Pro. and in almost all examples more than one whitespaces act as delimiters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split on *two* spaces, then trim any excess you might get in your results (would occur if you have an odd number of spaces)

```
List<string> splitStrings = myString.Split(new[]{"  "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, not sure if this will cover all your cases:

```
var regex = new Regex("  +");
var result = regex.Split("Line 1     Component Name             Revision        Quantity   Unit");
```

Result:

```
Line 1
Component Name
Revision
Quantity
Unit
```

Comment: +1 it worked too! thanks for alternate options than string.split

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always use :

```
String newStr = str.Split("<White space><White space>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here u r...

```
String fields = "He rl  lo vjdvd    fcsd";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\s\\s*" );

String[] split = pattern.split(fields);
for (String string : split) {
    //Use values here
}
```